# Requisição sendo Barrada pelo CORS policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, apache

Estou tentando montar meu Front End utilizando a API do Icinga, mas estou me deparando constantemente com o seguinte erro:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://icinga.ultraip.com.br/cgi-bin/icinga/status.cgi?search_string=&jsonoutput'
>   from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Já tentei de tudo, vi todos os tutoriais possíveis na internet e não consegui. Mas o que me deixa mais curioso, é que consigo fazer essa mesma requisição pelo Postman, sem nenhuma dificuldade.

Lembrando que:

1. Estou fazendo requisição para uma API que possui Basic Auth, o login e senha, estou passando no Header, criptografado, mas sem sucesso.
2. A mesma coisa sendo feita no Postman, não retorna erro nenhum, muito pelo contrário, eu passei direto, sem nenhuma dor de cabeça.

Agora, minhas dúvidas se concentram no seguinte: Como o Postman faz isso e se há a possibilidade de eu ver a requisição que foi feita pelo Postman, para poder copiá-la.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    type: 'GET'
});
```

Comment: O navegador vai bloquear pois a API não possui o *header* `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Uma forma de burlar isso é utilizando uma linguagem *back-end*, por exemplo: PHP.

Comment: Então quem está fazendo isso, é meu Browser?

Comment: Sim. É o navegador que bloqueia.

Comment: Você saberia me dizer onde posso colocar isso?

Comment: Isso?? Não entendi.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Tentei colocar pelo Apache2.conf mas não rolou

Comment: É necessário adicionar o *header* no site `ultraip.com.br`

Comment: Entendi. Você saberia me dizer qual seria o nome do arquivo?

Comment: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html